# Link against which libraries for GTK functions?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, gtk

may be this is a stupid question but I don't find a solution for my own. For a very simple application I use a few functions gdk_window_reparent() and gtk_widget_get_window().

But: against what library do I need to link in order to resolve these dependencies?

```
-lgtk
```

does not do the trick, the name must be something different...

Thanks!

Comment: Start reading the "Basics" section of the documentation... https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html#id-1.2.3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a program called `pkg-config` to generate the compiler and linker flags you need to build GTK+ software.

```
pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0            # compiler flags only
pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0              # linker flags only
pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0     # both
```

If you are building from a shell or a makefile, you can use backticks to capture the output from these programs and add them to the current command line. If you are using a build system, see how it integrates with `pkg-config`.